# how to call Two fragments in an activity on item click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

I am developing an application where i need to call two fragments on an activity replacing another fragment,one of the fragment will contain a Form   and another fragment will contain another Form  ,i don't have any idea how to do this,so any suggestion will be cordially appreciated,thanks in advance....

I want to replace Form on Click button. by R&D i come to know at this point i need to use to fragment with two layout each layout will contain Forms.

**Main Activity.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }    
}
```

**Fragment 1.**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    }
```

**Fragment 2.**

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

```
    FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(Home.newInstance(),"First");
    ft.add(Second.newInstance(),"Second");
    ft.commit();
```

So here you are added multiple fragment into the stack

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to replace Fragment1 with Fragment2, you replace the fragment.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment)